# Can't populatemy ListView from Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have created two xml files, and my custom view of 3 rows, 2 firsts are texts, and the last a button to delete data:

XML of the activity:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

listpoids.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPoids" />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Supprimer"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSupprimer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I did my adaper:

```
public class PoidsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mListPoids;

    public PoidsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListPoids = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListPoids.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mListPoids.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final holder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listpoids, null);
            holder = new holder();
            holder.mTvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
            holder.mTvMediaName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPoids);
            holder.mImageUrl = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSupprimer);
    return view;
    }

    public class holder {
        public Button mImageUrl;
        public TextView mTvTitle;
        public TextView mTvMediaName;
    }
}
```

And the database handler to get all of the rows:

```
    public List<Poids> getAllPoids() {


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Poids> poidsList = new ArrayList<Poids>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_POIDS,
                new String[] {});
/*
        List<Poids> poidsList = new ArrayList<Poids>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POIDS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
*/
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Poids poid = new Poids();
                poid.setPoids(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                poid.setDate_enr(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                poidsList.add(poid);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return poidsList;
    }
```

To finish how I call it:

```
    db.getAllPoids();
    List<Poids> poids = db.getAllPoids();

    ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    newData = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Poids val : poids) {

        newData.add(val.getDate_enr());
        newData.add(String.valueOf(val.getPoids()));
        //String log = "Id: " + val.getId() + " ,Date: " + val.getDate_enr() + " ,Poids: " + val.getPoids() + " ,Evolution: " + val.getEvolution() ;
        // Writing Contacts to log
        //Log.d("Name: ", log);
    }

    PoidsAdapter  mAdapter = new PoidsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listpoids, newData);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But it doesn't work, I'm in a fragment.

UPDATE:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listpoids, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mTvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        holder.mTvMediaName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPoids);
        holder.mImageUrl = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSupprimer);
    final Poids poids = mListPoids.get(position);
        holder.mTvTitle.setText(poids.getDate_enr().toString());
        holder.mTvMediaName.setText(String.valueOf(poids.getPoids()).toString());

    return view;
}
```

I think the error is here beceuse I see the two rows, but at setAdapter or something like this, here is missing something i think:

```
public class MonPoidsFragment extends Fragment {

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

    public MonPoidsFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.accueil_activity, container, false);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monpoids_activity, container, false);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        db.getAllPoids();
        List<Poids> poids = db.getAllPoids();

        ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        PoidsAdapter  mAdapter = new PoidsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listpoids, poids);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public Cursor getDetails() {
        return db.getReadableDatabase().query("Poids ", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        //This will return all data in your table.
    }
}
```

Database Helper:

```
// Getting All Contacts
public List<Poids> getAllPoids() {
    List<Poids> poidsList = new ArrayList<Poids>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POIDS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Poids poid = new Poids();
            poid.setPoids(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            poid.setDate_enr(cursor.getString(2));
            //poid.setPoids(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            //poid.setDate_enr(cursor.getString(1));
            // Adding contact to list
            poidsList.add(poid);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return poidsList;
}
```

Comment: could you describe more what didn't work? no results being shown? or ... ?

Comment: @ccsnoopy I have listpoids.xml displayed so 2 textview with  "TextView" as value and the button, like if the lstview just show up the xml file

Comment: The children of the listview will be populated by your adapter, why do you have 2 textviews and button as children of listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually assign anything to the `TextView`, other than assigning the holder to view components in `getView()`, you need to also assign them values.

Example:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final holder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listpoids, null);
        holder = new holder();
        holder.mTvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        holder.mTvMediaName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPoids);
        holder.mImageUrl = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSupprimer);
        holder.mTvTitle.setText("something you need to assign from some data");
        holder.mTvMediaName.setText("this as well..");
return view;
}
```

Also, unrelated to the problem, since inflating view is an expensive process, you should check first whether the `View` has been inflated before you inflate.

You could check this: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Comment: Work but I get only one values:(

Comment: i"m wondering why you could pass in `List<Poid>` into the Adapter when it asked you for `List<String>`? Does Poid extend String? It might be because you pass in Poid to String.

Comment: by one value, did you mean you only see 1 row? or many rows but the same values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110955/discussion-between-ccsnoopy-and-bjm).

Comment: When I debug mAdapter of: listView.setAdapter(mAdapter); contains 2 lines in mListPoids, but I don't know why they're only one rows which showed